# Выдают ошибку invalid syntax

Tags: python

Начал изучать Python пишу программу по примеру и выдаёт invalid syntax помогите разобраться.

```
number=23
running=True

while running:
    quess = int (input('Введите целое число: '))

    if quess == number :
        print('Поздравляю вы угадали.')
        running = False #Это останавливает цикл While
elif quess < number
    print('Нет, загаданное число немного больше этого.')
else:
    print('Нет. загаданное число немного меньше этого.')
else:
    print ('Цикл while закончен')
    #Здесь можете выполнять все что вам ешё нцужно
print ('Завершение')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Двоеточие после `quess < number`?

Answer (score 1):

`elif` и `else` должны быть на том же уровне что и `if`

```
while running:
    quess = int (input('Введите целое число: '))

    if quess == number :
        print('Поздравляю вы угадали.')
        running = False #Это останавливает цикл While
    elif quess < number
        print('Нет, загаданное число немного больше этого.')
    else:
        print('Нет. загаданное число немного меньше этого.')
else:
    print ('Цикл while закончен')
    #Здесь можете выполнять все что вам ешё нцужно
print ('Завершение')
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

потому что elif и следующий за ним else должны быть на уровень выше

```
number=23
running=True

while running:
    quess = int (input('Введите целое число: '))

    if quess == number :
        print('Поздравляю вы угадали.')
        running = False #Это останавливает цикл While
    elif quess < number
        print('Нет, загаданное число немного больше этого.')
    else:
        print('Нет. загаданное число немного меньше этого.')
else:
    print ('Цикл while закончен')
    #Здесь можете выполнять все что вам ешё нцужно
print ('Завершение')
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.